# Which national identity card number to enter in a UK visa application as an Indian US permanent resident?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, applications, us-residents

I am an Indian national residing in the USA as a permanent resident (Green Card holder). I am applying for a standard visitor visa to travel to the UK. There is a question about a national identity card number. What national identity number is expected? Is it the Green Card number, Social Security Number or should I leave this field blank (not applicable)?

Comment: Do you have an Indian national identity number?

Comment: If the answer to @RobertColumbia's question is "no" then you should either leave the question blank or enter "none" or something to that effect.  They're interested in identity cards issued by India, and the US does not issue national identity cards.

Comment: Just leave blank. For Indian citizen, its not important. I got the visa without mentioning anything.

Answer (score 6):

The national ID number in India would be the 12-digit *Aadhar number*. If you don't have an Aadhar card **or** don't know the number by heart, leave the field blank.

Answer (score 4):

You can mention the Indian Aadhar card if you have one.